# How can combine rows of a table with sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

| Type | rank |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| A | 8 |

And i want convert it to this table with sql query:

| Type | rank |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 7 |
| A | 8 |

How can I do this with and with out window functions?

Comment: Can you explain, in words, what you are trying to do? (and why "without window functions")

Comment: Do you have to do it with SQL? It looks easier to do with a programming language.

Comment: pretty sure he's just getting the max rank of each contiguous group.

Comment: I have two type A and B. I want select any type with maximum rank (for example A) until visiting other type(for example B) . And agin for other type (for example B).

Comment: I want use openquery for quryin a mysql.and it doesn't allow me use window function in query.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland  yes i want do that

Comment: @Barmar I must use sql. And openquery.

Comment: One of the principles of relational data is that a table is comprised of _unordered_ sets of rows. There's no such thing as "contiguous groups" unless you can order the rows by some column or expression.

Comment: @BillKarwin Looks like it's ordered by the `rank` column, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @Barmar But the groups are not ordered. If one were to `ORDER BY "rank"` alone, it would not return the rows in the order the OP says they want.

Comment: @BillKarwin It looks like it is. The first group is `A rank 1-2`. The second group is `B rank 3`. Third group is `A rank 4`, Next group is `B rank 5-7`. He wants the last row in each of these groups.

Comment: @Barmar, You are willing to make a lot more assumptions about the data than I am! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this without window functions, but they are a vast improvement over the kind of workarounds you had to do before mySQL got them.  Here is a solution with @variables.  I use the variables to increment a bucket by one every time the type changes, then group on the type and the bucket to get the maxRank for each bucket.  Here is a fiddle and the query:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=12bdc5fbd517905e758a8898025da3c9

```
select `type`, bucket, max(rank) as maxRank from (
  select `type`, rank, 
    @bucket := @bucket + if(`type` = @curr, 0, 1) as bucket,
    @curr := `type`
  from table1
  join (select @curr:='', @bucket:=0) v
  order by rank
) t group by bucket
```

I create the variables inside a join.  You could also declare them outside of the query, like so:

```
set @curr:='', @bucket:=0;

select `type`, bucket, max(rank) as maxRank from (
  select `type`, rank, 
    @bucket := @bucket + if(`type` = @curr, 0, 1) as bucket,
    @curr := `type`
  from table1
  order by rank
) t group by bucket
```

Sometimes it's easier to declare them inside a join, and sometimes as separate statements.  It just depends on your use case.

Two things to bear in mind:

1. don't name your field names the same thing as a reserved word.  You can do it, and you can make it work, but it will be a lot easier to just pick a different field name.  This is why type is in backticks.  mySQL will let you do it without the backticks, depending on the situation, but then sometimes it will fail on you in others and you'll eat up a lot of time trying to figure out why the same exact query fails in some uses and not others.  Plus it's a little confusing.  Just pick something else.
2. session variables are deprecated and subject to removal in future versions of mySQL.  I also don't think they're ANSI compliant, so porting this to another database probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can do it:

```
SELECT `type`,`rank`
FROM (
   SELECT
     `type`,
     lag(`type`) over (order by `rank` desc) as L,
     case when `type`=lag(`type`) over (order by `rank` desc) then 1 else 0 end C,
     `rank`
   FROM table1
   ORDER BY `rank`
) x WHERE c=0
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e12a00ca3d648de92002a75105a6ca4e)

Sorry, I have no knowledge of `openquery`, and I am too lazy right now to search for it.....

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the mysql version is 5. And  the window function doesn't work.

Comment: hey @Tavakoli, you can workaround window functions with variables, I'll try to put together a fiddle in mySQL but it may take me a couple of hours to get to it.